# dynamic memory allocation for auto_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic, auto-ptr

This is a sample code of my program. Here I am dynamically allocating memory using std::auto_ptr and entering values( in function) after that I am again allocation memory for the same variable. So Do the previously allocated memory will be deallocated when allocated a new memory for the same. I am doubtful about this since I am using std::auto_ptr. Thanks in advance.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <memory>
  #include <windows.h>

  std::auto_ptr<HANDLE> *eventHandle;

  void function()
  {
    eventHandle = new std::auto_ptr<HANDLE>[5];
    std::auto_ptr<HANDLE> handle(new HANDLE);
    *handle = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);
    eventHandle[0] = handle;
  }

  void f2()
  {
    if(NULL == eventHandle)
    {
      std::cout<<" HANDLE NULL";
    }
  }

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
    function();
    f2();
    function();
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Writing `new std::auto_ptr` defeats the purpose of auto_ptr.

Comment: @Pubby: this is a dynamically-sized array of `auto_ptr`, though. Or it would be, if the `5` wasn't a hard-coded constant. A dynamically-sized array doesn't defeat the purpose of `auto_ptr` in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
std::auto_ptr<HANDLE> *eventHandle;
```

you have a raw pointer, so when you reassign it the previous value is just overwritten and the array of objects of type `auto_ptr` previously pointed to is leaked.

Answer (score 2):

In your example : the HANDLE pointers are smart pointers but not the array of `std::auto_ptr`. In this case you'll have to call `delete [] eventHandle` prior to the second `function()` call, this will also delete the HANDLE smart pointers.

However, the HANDLE objects would have to be closed by [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function prior to deletion, so I question the need of smart pointers here since you'll always know when the HANDLE is no more needed and the pointer to the object has to be deleted.

P.S. `std::auto_ptr` is a bit flawed. If you have access to VS2010, I would suggest you to use `std::shared_ptr`.

P.P.S. if you want to test for NULL, you should always initialize pointers to NULL, they're aren't by default. `std::auto_ptr<HANDLE> *eventHandle = NULL;`

Comment: std::shared_ptr's bit more expensive than auto_ptr. It's std::unique_ptr which is the C++11 more direct replacement for auto_ptr.

Comment: Most important is that with either `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, you can get rid of the nasty `new[]`, and use a nice `std::vector` or `std::array` of smart pointers.

Comment: @SteveJessop absolutely, that was one of many auto_ptr flaws to be incompatible with standard containers.